# change viewport meta tag with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I was wondering if it is possible to add a meta tag using jquery to an html page before the page loads.
The reason why I ask, is because I have a page with no viewport meta tag on and it should have it only when the resolution drops below 700px - `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>`

The reason being, I have html markup for mobile site (using media queries) & also html markup for desktop version ( I don't have one for tablets). I want to make sure html markup designed for desktop is rendered properly on tablet on page load and also when we change the device orientation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AndyHolmes - Having a viewport `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>` by default is causing the page to overflow on tablets when we change the orientation multiple times.

Comment: Realised that after my comment! haha. Check my answer :)

Comment: You should be handling this with CSS. If the viewport tag is causing issues on tablets or desktops then your CSS is badly coded!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using jQuery you can do it like the following:

```
if ($(window).width() < 700) {
   $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>');
}
```

**EDIT**

To have the viewport tag by default, then remove it above 699px:

HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
</head>
```

jQuery:

```
if ($(window).width() > 699) {
   $('head').remove('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't the above happen when the page has already loaded ? Unfortunately I need the meta tag to be added before the page loads - if it is possible at all.

Comment: then have it by default and remove it > 700

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this doesn't work. This would just remove the tag from the html. But, by this time the html is already loaded assuming it has the viewport on all devices. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I dont understand your issue then, you want the tag to appear on certain sizes, which i've shown, and then offered how to remove it, which i've shown. Have you actually tried the code? The viewport only works if the meta is actually there

Answer (score 0):

Try this (you don't need the `/` at the end of the meta tag anymore):

```
if(screen.width < 700) {
    $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can as soon as the jQuery library is loaded and the head is registered at the DOM:

```
if (jQuery('html').outerWidth(true) < 700) {
  jQuery.('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>');
}
```